classifying L to P or NPC or NPH. and prove it.
is $L=\{\varphi|\varphi \text{is a CNF satisfyable formula.let n be the number of variable in }\varphi \text{, out of } 2^n \text{ possible assingment to the variable of } \varphi \text{at least } 2^{n-1} \text{ are not satisfiable} \}$
Is L in P or NPC or NPH. and prove it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
